# How to create non-modularized language packs

Tags: magento2, localisation, translate, language-package

What are the structural differences and how do you create the non-modularized language pack?  Per https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html#m2devgde-xlate-languagepack the doc explains there are two types of language packs...

> Magento enables you to create the following types of language packages:
>
> 1. A set of `.csv` files for modules and themes. These packages files are intended to be deployed in modules.
> 2. Language packages that contain a entire dictionary in one directory.
>
>    - You can distribute this language package as a standalone component (similar to modules and themes). Interestingly, it violates Magento’s modularity principles on purpose; that is, so that a system integrator can translate variations provided by extensions.

It's this second type that I am interested in trying to understand more clearly.  I can create the first one using `i18n:pack` as outlined in https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-example2 , but I don't see any specific details on how to create a self-contained pack that doesn't distribute all the files into each individual module directory.

I've tested manually putting the files in the **/app/i18n** directory and as far as I can tell the translations appear to be working.  Is this structure (shown below) the correct setup?

- /app

  - /i18n

    - /MyCustomNamespace

      - /it_it

        - composer.json
        - it_IT.csv
        - language.xml
        - registration.php

I did this without using the `i18n:pack` command because as far as I can tell that just divvies up the translations into individual it_IT.csv files within each module.  Do I need to complete any other steps aside from putting the files in place to complete the setup officially?